# Training batches: which Tensorflow method is the right one?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network

I'm trying to train a very simple neural network to classify samples of data where some classes necessarily succeed others - this is why I decided to let the input data enter the network in batches. Using Tensorflow, apparently you get multiple ways of declaring batches, like `tf.data.Dataset.batch` (with which I currently train using the Adam Optimizer) and `tf.train.batch`. Where is the difference? Should the methods be used together or are they exclusive? In the latter case: which one should I prefer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tf.train.*` is an older API, more complex and prone to errors than the `tf.data.*` one (you need to take care yourself of queues, thread runners, coordinator, etc). For your stated purpose (batching data and feeding it to a model), the two are functionally equivalent, as in both achieve your goal. However, you should consider using `tf.data` as that's both simpler to use and the [currently recommended way](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/datasets_quickstart) to handle input datasets.